# extracting specific values between given start and end values R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, datatable

I have matrix M with n1 number of rows and n2 number of column,i am trying to do is extracting values where its found value greater than or equal to 0.50  and it should take all values until its found value less than 0.50. and also take 2 values before and after the starting and ending points.I am thinking to start with for loop but I am confused what I should put in condition so that It reads all line of matrix and give output.It would be great if anyone could share any idea.

Example: M:

```
M<- rbind(c(0.10, 0.20 ,0.40 ,0.50 ,0.49 ,0.52, 0.67, 0.58 ,0.77, 0.34, 0.31, 0.21, 0.87 ,0.65, 0.54, 0.89, 0.78, 0.50, 0.22, 0.34  
),c(0.31, 0.28, 0.74, 0.87 ,0.65, 0.54, 0.78, 0.45, 0.34, 0.41, 0.19 ,0.12 ,0.99, 0.99 ,0.89 ,0.78, 0.50, 0.66 ,0.26, 0.14))

M

  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,] 0.10 0.20 0.40 0.50 0.49 0.52 0.67 0.58 0.77  0.34  0.31  0.21  0.87  0.65  0.54  0.89  0.78  0.50  0.22  0.34
[2,] 0.31 0.28 0.74 0.87 0.65 0.54 0.78 0.45 0.34  0.41  0.19  0.12  0.99  0.99  0.89  0.78  0.50  0.66  0.26  0.14
```

Desired output :

```
0.20 0.40 0.50 0.49 0.52 0.67 0.58 0.77 0.34 0.31
0.31 0.21 0.87 0.65 0.54 0.89 0.78 0.50 0.22 0.34   
0.31 0.28 0.74 0.87 0.65 0.54 0.78 0.50 0.34 0.41
0.19 0.12 0.99 0.99 0.89 0.78 0.54 0.66 0.26 0.14
```

```
for (i in nrows(M))
what should be the condition  here?
```

What I meant by occurrence :
after finishing each occurrence it should be in new line,as you see the after 1st accordance 2nd one is new line

```
1st occurrence 0.20 0.40 0.50 0.49 0.52 0.67 0.58 0.77 0.34 0.31
2nd occurrence 0.31 0.21 0.87 0.65 0.54 0.89 0.78 0.50 0.22 0.34    
3rd occurrence 0.31 0.28 0.74 0.87 0.65 0.54 0.78 0.50 0.34 0.41
4th occurrence 0.19 0.12 0.99 0.99 0.89 0.78 0.54 0.66 0.26 0.14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I have somewhat of an answer. There is several layers to this problem as I understood it. Besides finding the consecutive occurring numbers above 0.5, there is a need to include values if they are "surrounded" by values > = 0.5, so I have also addressed that.  Note that instead of looping over each row, the matrix is turned into one vector (you can also use a loop).

```
#Your data
M<- rbind(c(0.10, 0.20 ,0.40 ,0.50 ,0.49 ,0.52, 0.67, 0.58 ,0.77, 0.34, 0.31, 0.21, 0.87 ,0.65, 0.54, 0.89, 0.78, 0.50, 0.22, 0.34  
),c(0.31, 0.28, 0.74, 0.87 ,0.65, 0.54, 0.78, 0.45, 0.34, 0.41, 0.19 ,0.12 ,0.99, 0.99 ,0.89 ,0.78, 0.50, 0.66 ,0.26, 0.14))

#make the matrix into a single vector, with buffer zeros between rows
m <- cbind(M, rep(c(NA), nrow(M)), rep(c(NA), nrow(M)))
a <- c(t(m))

#make a coresponding binary vecto of the desired values
b <- ifelse(a >= 0.5, 1, 0)

#cumsum that restarts with zeroes
d <- ave(b, cumsum(b == 0), FUN = cumsum)

#patch the holes in desired values: 
#if one value =< 0.5, is surounded by values >= 0.5, consider this value desireble
ind1 <- c(d[-1], 0)
ind2 <- c(0, d[-length(d)])
q <- ifelse((d + ind1 > 0 & d + ind2 > 0), 1, b)

#get start and end indecies for the desired values
z <- with(rle(q), {
  ok <- values == 1 & lengths & !is.na(values) >= 1
  ends <- cumsum(lengths)
  starts <- ends - lengths + 1
  data.frame(starts, ends)[ok, ]
})

## use the indecies to retrive he original values

#define a matrix to put results, using z to create corect dimensions
z$length <- z$ends - z$starts + 5
res <- matrix(NA, nrow(z), ncol = max(z$length))

#forloop to go trough each line of z, creating one line for each output
for (j in 1:nrow(z)) {
  res[ j , 1:z$length[j]] <- a[(z$starts[j]-2):(z$ends[j]+2)]
}

res
```

PS. there is a missing value (0.5) from your data, when comparing to your desired output

Comment: thanks it worked,just small query ` z$length <- z$ends - z$starts + 5 ` why you have put `+5` ?

Comment: Oh, that is to accommodate the two values before and after start/end. So that the matrix would have the right number of columns

Comment: i still didn't get...do i need to change this value based on my matrix dimensions Or it would be same all time?

Comment: This would be the same all the time, since you constantly want the four extra columns. the other dimensions are calculated from the start and end indexes. so if the z values where start = 2 and end= 5. the length or number of columns needed is (5-2)+1 + 4  = 8. the +1 is because you want to "include" the start value so to say. and the dimensions of the empty matrix to allocate the results is determined from the maximum of the z$length column. Inside the for-loop z$length is used to only put as many values as is available, otherwise duplicates would appear. Hpe it makes sense :)

Comment: Jost.thanks fot explanation..i have last query it i want to change the constant number then doni meed to change this number? Like now i want four extra column.. what if i want to have fourty extra column?do i need to change 5 ?

Comment: well yes, the 5 is essentially the number of columns found +2 in the front and two in the back. so if you change the 5, just make sure you change the "-2" and "+2" inside the loop, so that the dimensions fit.